# Combine design time menu elements into databound menu item binding

Tags: wpf

Hopefully I got the vernacular right on my question so I don't throw people completely off.

I have a menu that is data bound and using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` that handles the various nested types in my binding object. So far everything is working fantastically; but now I would like to add a couple additional menu items to menu items of a certain type, but of course that breaks the binding as I cannot bind to a collection that already contains elements. `CompositeCollection` seems to be what I am looking for but I keep running into syntax errors when trying to apply that to my `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

```
        <Menu.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ODIF:PluginContainer}" ItemsSource="{Binding Instance.Devices}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Instance.Devices}"/>
                        <MenuItem>One more item!</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem>Two more items!</MenuItem>
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding PluginIcon}" Width="16" Height="16">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PluginIcon}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PluginName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ODIF:Device}" ItemsSource="{Binding InputChannels}">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding StatusIcon}" Width="16" Height="16">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusIcon}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ODIF:DeviceChannel}">
                <local:ChannelBox Channel="{Binding}" Width="200" Click="ChannelClicked"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.Resources>
```

This throws:

> The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was
>   expected: "BindingBase".

and

> Property 'ItemsSource' does not support values of type 'CompositeCollection'.

Comment: Also I *COULD* bind my menu to a programatically created composite collection that has my additional menu items, but when I have so much of my binding working in XAML and all nice and clean, doing the compositing in c# just feels dirty and hack-job-ish. Not to mention unless I do some extra hack-job work to make sure my collectionChanged event isn't swallowed up in the code I would lose the dynamic updating as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to use a [converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb546926(v=vs.90).aspx) for solving your issue.

Let's suppose that `MenuModel` is a class which represents a menu item. It is really simple:

```
public class MenuModel
{
    private List<MenuModel> children = new List<MenuModel>();

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList Children
    {
        get
        {
            return children;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have our XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <collections:ArrayList x:Key="someOtherMenus">
        <local:MenuModel Description="Menu A">
            <local:MenuModel.Children>
                <local:MenuModel Description="SubMenu i" />
                <local:MenuModel Description="SubMenu ii" />
            </local:MenuModel.Children>
        </local:MenuModel>
        <local:MenuModel Description="Menu B" />
    </collections:ArrayList>

</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuModels}">
        <Menu.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                    <Binding ConverterParameter="someOtherMenus">
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <local:CompositeCollectionConverter />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>


                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="3" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
    </Menu>
    <TextBlock Text="text" Margin="10" />
</DockPanel>
```

So now we can consider the converter implementation:

```
public class CompositeCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MenuModel menuModel = value as MenuModel;

        if (parameter != null)
        {
            CollectionContainer collectionContainer = new CollectionContainer();
            collectionContainer.Collection = menuModel.Children;

            CompositeCollection compositeCollection = new CompositeCollection();
            compositeCollection.Add(collectionContainer);

            collectionContainer = new CollectionContainer();
            collectionContainer.Collection = (IEnumerable)App.Current.MainWindow.FindResource(parameter);
            compositeCollection.Add(collectionContainer);

            return compositeCollection;
        }
        else
        {
            return menuModel.Children;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

As you can see it uses its parameter to get a specific resource (in our case I am using the resource called "someOtherMenus", which is an IEnumerable of `MenuModels`).

Of course the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is recursive so the "someOtherMenus" `MenuModels` will be added to each level (but the first one) of your `Menu`.

I hope my sample can help you.

Comment: I ended up going with something almost identical to this. Shame there isnt a simpler way to do this.

Comment: @Wobbles, you are right, it should be simplier. Anyway, if you need some data to bind to your user interface just for design purposes then you can consider [this walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602274(v=vs.95).aspx)